# How to get current price tier from Store Kit Framework?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to show an extra label for in-app purchase if current price tier is tier1.
Are there any other methods than compare localized price?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, SKProduct does not expose the price tier directly.

However you could create a plist, or some other type of data store, that mapped the product id to the price tier. If you have web services then you could do this dynamically if the product price changes. If you have to bundle it with your app and you change the prices often, then this won't work.